# check for exact presence in a queryset django, jinja 2

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

In my case, I have a question to check if the exact string name of a model does exist in a query set. here is my code:

`views.py:`

```
if Despiking.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
    filtered_projects = Despiking.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context.update({
        'filtered_projects': filtered_projects.__str__(),
    })
```

`Despiking Model class:`

```
class Despiking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    # Some other models...
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

`template.html:`

```
{% if info.project_name in filtered_projects %}
    <!-- some HTML elements -->
{% else %}
    <!-- other HTML elements -->
{% endif %}
```

In my code, there is no difference between `"my project"` and `"project"` as `info.project_name` model. because of that the `"project"` word exists in the query set when I have only the `"my project"` in it. so using `{% if info.project_name in filtered_projects %}` works the same (the condition of `if` will be `True`) because that `"project"` word exists in the query set because of the `"my project"`. what can I do to check the exact string in it?

Comment: Can you please share the `Despiking` model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`__exact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#exact) or [`__iexact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) for exact matching in case-sensitive and case-insensitive operations respectively.

You can use following queryset which would only have the word `my project`:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

if Despiking.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
    filtered_projects = Despiking.objects.filter(Q(user=request.user) & Q(project_name__exact="my project"))
    context.update({
        'filtered_projects': filtered_projects,
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have edited my question and added the necessary parts of the `Despiking` model.

Comment: @Silent Do you want a solution from a queryset like `filtered_projects` as you created in view or want to make a method in the model itself for filtering?

Comment: a solution from the queryset in views.py will be great. but if you are able to share both with me I will be appreciated to learn 2 new subjects from you. thanks.

Comment: @Silent All right, but try current solution.

Comment: the problem with this code is `the "my project"` word. the project's names are going to be dynamic and are chosen by the user. whatever he/she wants. and I expect to show the HTML elements based on them. it should not be important what the `project_name` is. user can type whatever he/she wants.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251563/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-silent).